# Установить фильтрацию данных для нескольких таблиц QTableView

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtableview

Нужно было для таблицы добавить фильтры, на одном сайте нашел работающий скрипт https://question-it.com/questions/1356815/kak-sozdat-filtry-dlja-qtableview-v-pyqt. 
В своей программе планирую создать несколько таблиц. Так как у таблиц будут разными только содержимое и место отображения, а функции будут одинаковыми, то я решил передавать содержимое и место отображения в сам класс. 
После этого данные отображаются, но фильтры не работают.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

Это **`мой скрипт`**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 301, 281))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 50, 301, 281))
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class table_filter(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, widget, model, parent=None):
        super(table_filter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget  = widget
        self.lineEdit       = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.view           = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox       = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.label          = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        #self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Regex Filter")
        self.model = model
        # self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        # for rowName in range(3*5):
        #     self.model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
        #         [   QtGui.QStandardItem("row {0} col {1}".format(rowName, column))    
        #             for column in range(3)
        #             ]
        #         )

        self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Column {0}".format(x) for x in range(self.model.columnCount())])

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)

        self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):
        self.logicalIndex   = logicalIndex
        self.menuValues     = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        self.signalMapper   = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)  

        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.logicalIndex)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)

        valuesUnique = [    self.model.item(row, self.logicalIndex).text()
                            for row in range(self.model.rowCount())
                            ]

        actionAll = QtWidgets.QAction("All", self)
        actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()

        for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):              
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(actionName, self)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)  
            action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)  
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)

        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)  

        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())        

        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(self.logicalIndex)

        self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  "",
                                        QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                        QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                        )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  stringAction,
                                        QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitive,
                                        QtCore.QRegExp.FixedString
                                        )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        search = QtCore.QRegExp(    text,
                                    QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                    QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                    )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                           #  +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        for rowName in range(3*5):
            self.model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                [   QtGui.QStandardItem("row {0} col {1}".format(rowName, column))    
                    for column in range(3)
                    ]
                )

        self.model2 = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        for rowName in range(3*5):
            self.model2.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                [   QtGui.QStandardItem("строка {0} столбец {1}".format(rowName, column))    
                    for column in range(3)
                    ]
                )

        table_filter(self.widget, self.model)
        table_filter(self.widget_2, self.model2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Main()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

А это скрипт, на основе которого я сделал свой:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class myWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget  = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.lineEdit       = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.view           = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox       = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.label          = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Regex Filter")

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        for rowName in range(3*5):
            self.model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                [   QtGui.QStandardItem("row {0} col {1}".format(rowName, column))    
                    for column in range(3)
                    ]
                )

        self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Column {0}".format(x) for x in range(self.model.columnCount())])

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)

        self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):
        self.logicalIndex   = logicalIndex
        self.menuValues     = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        self.signalMapper   = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)  

        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.logicalIndex)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)

        valuesUnique = [    self.model.item(row, self.logicalIndex).text()
                            for row in range(self.model.rowCount())
                            ]

        actionAll = QtWidgets.QAction("All", self)
        actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()

        for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):              
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(actionName, self)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)  
            action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)  
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)

        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)  

        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())        

        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(self.logicalIndex)

        self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  "",
                                        QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                        QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                        )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  stringAction,
                                        QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitive,
                                        QtCore.QRegExp.FixedString
                                        )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        search = QtCore.QRegExp(    text,
                                    QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                    QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                    )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myWindow()
    main.show()
    main.resize(400, 600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Напиши в телегу @budda1123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы почти были у  цели.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 301, 281))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        
        self.widget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 50, 301, 281))
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class Table_Filter(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, widget, model, parent=None):
        super(Table_Filter, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.centralwidget  = widget
        self.lineEdit       = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.view           = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox       = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.label          = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.label.setText("Regex Filter")
        self.model = model

        self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.comboBox.addItems(["Column {0}".format(x) for x in range(self.model.columnCount())])

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)

        self.horizontalHeader = self.view.horizontalHeader()
        self.horizontalHeader.sectionClicked.connect(self.on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_view_horizontalHeader_sectionClicked(self, logicalIndex):
        self.logicalIndex   = logicalIndex
        self.menuValues     = QtWidgets.QMenu(self)
        self.signalMapper   = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)  

        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)
        self.comboBox.setCurrentIndex(self.logicalIndex)
        self.comboBox.blockSignals(True)

        valuesUnique = [    self.model.item(row, self.logicalIndex).text()
                            for row in range(self.model.rowCount())
                            ]

        actionAll = QtWidgets.QAction("All", self)
        actionAll.triggered.connect(self.on_actionAll_triggered)
        self.menuValues.addAction(actionAll)
        self.menuValues.addSeparator()

        for actionNumber, actionName in enumerate(sorted(list(set(valuesUnique)))):              
            action = QtWidgets.QAction(actionName, self)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(action, actionNumber)  
            action.triggered.connect(self.signalMapper.map)  
            self.menuValues.addAction(action)

        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(self.on_signalMapper_mapped)  

        headerPos = self.view.mapToGlobal(self.horizontalHeader.pos())        

        posY = headerPos.y() + self.horizontalHeader.height()
        posX = headerPos.x() + self.horizontalHeader.sectionPosition(self.logicalIndex)

        self.menuValues.exec_(QtCore.QPoint(posX, posY))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionAll_triggered(self):
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  "",
                                        QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                        QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                        )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_signalMapper_mapped(self, i):
        stringAction = self.signalMapper.mapping(i).text()
        filterColumn = self.logicalIndex
        filterString = QtCore.QRegExp(  stringAction,
                                        QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitive,
                                        QtCore.QRegExp.FixedString
                                        )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(filterString)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(filterColumn)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        search = QtCore.QRegExp(    text,
                                    QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                    QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                    )

        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):              
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)                       # self
        for rowName in range(3 * 5):
            self.model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                [   QtGui.QStandardItem("row {0} col {1}".format(rowName, column))    
                    for column in range(3)
                    ]
                )

        self.model2 = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        for rowName in range(3*5):
            self.model2.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                [   QtGui.QStandardItem("строка {0} столбец {1}".format(rowName, column))    
                    for column in range(3)
                    ]
                )

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
# ---        table_filter(self.widget, self.model)
# ---        table_filter(self.widget_2, self.model2)
        
        self.table_filter = Table_Filter(self.widget, self.model)          # +++
        self.table_filter2 = Table_Filter(self.widget_2, self.model2)      # +++
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Main()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]